# How to read / query data from one userID Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data for a given user ID, which I am storing as a value in the database under each user. My database structure looks like below:

```
user: {
    UserID: { 
       uniqueId: {
         Name: ""
         Email: ""
         userId: ""
    }

    UserID: { 
       uniqueId: {
         Name: ""
         Email: ""
         userId: ""
    }
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work as it doesn't display anything on the app:

```
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
df.child("UsersTable").orderByChild("userid").equalTo(user.getUid())).addChildEventListener
```

even when I try to give a specific value like below, it still does not read from firebase:
------------- Updated:

I want to get all data from userID. so for example, I want to retrieve all information from fmXWU324VHdDb8v6h7gvNjRojnu33, which will be name, email and userid.

```
UserTable
{
  "fmXWU324VHdDb8v6h7gvNjRojnu33" : {
    "-KbJtw467nl6p253HZ537" : {
      "Name" : "name1",
      "Email" : "something1@something.com",
      "userid" : "fmXWU324VHdDb8v6h7gvNjRojnu33"
    }
  },
  "pJtC45fW0MMi352UiPWnWdIS7h88" : {
    "-Kb012ls9iMnzEL723o9I" : {
      "Name" : "name2",
      "Email" : "something2@something.com",
      "userid" : "pJtC45fW0MMi352UiPWnWdIS7h88"
    },
    "-Kb0aq0q25FJq38256SrC" : {
      "Name" : "name3",
      "Email" : "something3@something.com",
      "userid" : "pJtC45fW0MMi352UiPWnWdIS7h88"
    },
    "-Kb0atopfK64F6jy124Qi1u" : {
      "Name" : "name3",
      "Email" : "something1@something.com",
      "userid" : "pJtC45fW0MMi352UiPWnWdIS7h88"
  }
}
```

Update 2:

```
     DatabaseReference df= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .getReference("user").child(getCurrentUser().getUid());   

df.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        get(dataSnapshot);
                    }
            ....
            ...
```

**Update 3:**

I assume based on what I am looking for (getting all data under defined userId) the query should look something like this:

```
df.child("UserTable").child(user.getUid())).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
```

However, this is throwing this error:

```
Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.android.example.UserTable
```

Comment: Your data structure not clear to me. Please share a snippet of your actual JSON (as text, which you can get by clicking Export JSON in your Firebase Database console).

Comment: Please see update

Comment: I wrote an answer, but now realize that your question is different. You can get the results for a single user with: `df.child("UsersTable").child("user").child(user.getUid()).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() { ...`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen its not retrieving / showing anything on the application

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen please see update 3

Comment: That error comes from within `get()`, which re haven't seen. Please have a look at how to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because Stack Overflow is notoriously inefficient for remote debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Try Using `addChildEventListener` and Query like following..

```
mReference.child("user").orderByChild("userId").equalTo(user.getUid()).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        //deal with data object
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

OR use `addValueEventListener`

```
mReference.child("user").orderByChild("userId").equalTo(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

             //deal with data object

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //toastMsg(databaseError.getMessage());
            Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled: " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, I am not storing the uniqueId of the person it might be difficult to do it that way

Comment: if you are not doing anything with uniqueId than you can remove it. don't put unnecessary object of array.

Comment: I mean I am not storing the uniqueId  as a variable but it being used to create unique entries from same userID.

Comment: No need to put such things firebase will consider every object as unique entry if your data will be different.. see my updated answer

Comment: Can I just point out, when I did not have uniqueId previous data from the same user was being over written.

Comment: in the database UserId refers to the ID of each person, can I check if by child("UserID") you are referring to user.getUid()

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, basically each user can have more then 1 entry in the database under they userId, which is why I have uniqueID. Sorry my diagram didn't show that.

Comment: I hope you are pushing value in array, don't use set value for save data if you want to store every entry as unique.

Comment: have you try by querying as i suggested?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't retrieve anything

Comment: Okay replace `userId` to `uniqueId` check updated answer.

Comment: Please see updated post. I have pasted the actual data structure.

Comment: I am not keep an record of unique ID, so I am too sure how I can orderByChild("uniqueId")

Comment: okay so.. based on your updated structure you can directly query by using `orderByChild("userId")` check updated answer hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please get a idea from below code.

Order objects:

[image: Order objects]

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference();
DatabaseReference node = mDatabaseReference.child("order")

node.orderByChild("timestamp").equalTo("-KZFQLVAv_kARdfnNnib")
                   .addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);

private ValueEventListener mValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: " + snapshot.getValue());
            // Your code
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    };
```

This return the first order object. Hope you get the point Thanks! :)

Comment: Hi, I am little confused your saying orderByChild("timestamp").equalTo("-KZFQLVAv_kARdfnNnib"). but in your timestamp you don't have such value KZFQLVAv_kARdfnNnib but instead is it the value for your id

Comment: What it does is whole list `OrderBy` from timestamp in each object. And if you want to get one object you don't want to put `orderby` just ignore it.

Comment: `DatabaseReference mRef = mDatabaseReference.child("user") //in my example its "order"` then 
`node.addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);` this will return all users.

Comment: I want to get all info under 1 userID

Comment: Then `node.equalTo("-KZFQLVAv_kARdfnNnib").addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);` this should works.

Comment: Sorry, you cant get that way just put a for loop and filter your requirement from all users

Comment: If you know the id of that object then you can `node.child("-KZFQLVAv_kARdfnNnib").addValueEventListener(m‌​ValueEventListener);`

Answer (score 0):

Use something like the below code which i am using in my application and it works -

```
public static void storagesSetup(final Context context){

        if(!hasSignedInUser()) {
            **your business logic here**
            return;
        }

        // Write a message to the database
        final DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("cart").child(getCurrentUser().getUid());

        // Read from the database
        databaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.

                **put your business logic here**

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I get this error: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.project.users.usersTable

Answer (score 0):

A Firebase Database query inspects the child nodes directly under the location that you execute it on. If you want to order on a child property of those nodes (i.e. use `orderByChild()`), that property must exist at a fixed path under each child nodes.

In your case, you have two nested dynamic children, which means you:

- can query a known user for their results ordered by score
- can't query across all users for their results ordered by score

If you want to allow the latter query, you'll need to change your data model to allow it. For example, by keeping a list of all results across all players:

```
ResultsTable:{
    "-KbJtw467nl6p253HZ537" : {
      "Name" : "name1",
      "Email" : "something1@something.com",
      "userid" : "fmXWU324VHdDb8v6h7gvNjRojnu33"
    },
    "-Kb012ls9iMnzEL723o9I" : {
      "Name" : "name2",
      "Email" : "something2@something.com",
      "userid" : "pJtC45fW0MMi352UiPWnWdIS7h88"
    },
    "-Kb0aq0q25FJq38256SrC" : {
      "Name" : "name3",
      "Email" : "something3@something.com",
      "userid" : "pJtC45fW0MMi352UiPWnWdIS7h88"
    },
    "-Kb0atopfK64F6jy124Qi1u" : {
      "Name" : "name3",
      "Email" : "something1@something.com",
      "userid" : "pJtC45fW0MMi352UiPWnWdIS7h88"
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically, I can't  have userId of a person followed by pushid underneath that user for each entry? what I want to do is, retrieve all information under 1 user id which I define.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I realized after posting. That's a lot simpler. I left a comment with the needed code